# Propertyregex: escaping spaces in paths

Tags: macos, ant, ant-contrib

I have a problem with escaping spaces with ant-contrib's propertyregex.  The following works on windows:

```
<propertyregex property="env.ESCAPED_JOB_NAME" override="true"
 input="${env.JOB_NAME}" regexp=" " replace="\\\\ "
 defaultValue="${env.JOB_NAME}" />
```

This gives me a nicely escaped path so

```
/SomeFolder/On my machine/
```

becomes

```
/SomeFolder/On\ my\ machine/
```

However, the point is I want it to work on our OSX build machines, which it doesn't.  Somewhere along the line the \ get switched to / and the folders cannot be found.  This is the output I see on the Mac:

```
/SomeFolder/On/ my/ machine/
```

Which will clearly never work.  Any ideas?  Is there another way to escape spaces?

Edit:  This looks like it could be a problem with ANT's copy command.  I can echo the path correctly but the copy swaps the \ for /.  Is there an osx friendly way to do a copy?

Comment: what version of ant are you running?

Comment: Show more code please. Specifically the copy that is failing and how any properties it uses are set (if using properties other that `env.ESCAPED_JOB_NAME`)